# CodeIgniter ajax form validation not showing any message on screen

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I'd like some help please.

I'm having a form placed inside a bootstrap modal window.

```
<div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-body">

                <div id="ajaxResults"></div>

                <?php echo form_open('controller-name/form-process'), array('id' => 'modal-form'); ?>

                    <input type="hidden" name="title" id="hid-title" />

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php echo form_input('first_name', set_value('first_name', $this->input->post('first_name')), 'id="first-name" class="form-control" placeholder="First name"'); ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php echo form_input('last_name', set_value('last_name', $this->input->post('last_name')), 'id="last-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name"'); ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php echo form_input('email', set_value('email', $this->input->post('email')), 'id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"'); ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?php echo form_input('company', set_value('company', $this->input->post('company')), 'id="company" class="form-control" placeholder="Company"'); ?>
                    </div>

                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            </div><!-- /.modal-body -->

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn border-black" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn border-theme" id="form-submit-btn">Submit form</button>
            </div><!-- /.modal-footer -->

        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

When I click the `Submit the Form` button I'm sending an ajax request to my `form_process` controller where I do the form validation. Here's my code for the `form_process` function and the ajax script

```
public function form_process() {

    if ($this->input->post()) {

        $rules = array(
            'first_name' => array(
                'field' => 'first_name',
                'label' => 'First name',
                'rules' => 'required|trim|min_length[2]',
            ),
            'last_name' => array(
                'field' => 'last_name',
                'label' => 'Last name',
                'rules' => 'required|trim|min_length[2]',
            ),
            'email' => array(
                'field' => 'email',
                'label' => 'Email',
                'rules' => 'required|trim|valid_email',
            ),
            'company' => array(
                'field' => 'company',
                'label' => 'Company',
                'rules' => 'required|trim',
            ),
        );

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

        // validate the form
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

            $response = array(
                'status' => '200',
                'message' => 'Thank you! We have sent an email to ' . $this->input->post('email') . ' to get your white paper.',
            );

        } else {

            $response = array(
                'status' => '400',
                'message' => validation_errors(),
            );
        }

// return the result of the form process    

    $this->output->set_status_header($response['status'])->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
        ->set_output(json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))->_display();
        exit();

    }
```

The ajax script looks like this

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

                    $('#modal-form').show();
                    $('#ajaxResults').removeClass('alert alert-success alert-error');

                    // Button that triggered the modal
                    var button = $(event.relatedTarget); 

                    // Extract info from data-* attributes
                    var recipient = button.data('whatever');


                    // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
                    // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
                    var modal = $(this);
                    modal.find('.modal-title').html('New message to <br/>' + recipient);
                    modal.find('.modal-body input[type=hidden]').val(recipient);



// submit the form
                    $('#form-submit-btn').on('click', function (event){
                        event.preventDefault();

                        var url = $('#modal-form').attr('action');

                        // send ajax request
                        $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type : 'POST',
                        data : {
                            'first_name' : $('#first-name').val(),
                            'last_name' : $('#last-name').val(),
                            'email' : $('#email').val(),
                            'company' : $('#company').val(),
                            'title' : $('#hid-title').val(),
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success : function(response) {
                            alert(response.message);
                            // console.log(response.message);
                            $('#ajaxResults').removeClass('alert alert-success alert-error');

                            if (response.status == 200) {
                                $('#modal-form').hide();
                                $('#ajaxResults').addClass('alert alert-success').html(response.message);
                                alert('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
                            }

                            if (response.status == 400) {
                                $('#modal-form').show();
                                $('#ajaxResults').addClass('alert alert-error').html(response.reason);
                                alert('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(response){
                            // code ...
                            $('#ajaxResults').removeClass('alert alert-success alert-error');

                            if (response.status == 200) {
                                $('#modal-form').hide();
                                $('#ajaxResults').addClass('alert alert-success').html(response.message);
                                alert('CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC');
                            }

                            if (response.status == 400) {
                                $('#modal-form').show();
                                $('#ajaxResults').addClass('alert alert-error').html(response.reason);
                                alert('DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    });
                });
```

**EDIT** I did an update on my ajax script and placed some alert messages, as you can see. When I click the `submit` button without submitting the form ( so there are errors), the alert `DDDDDDD` pops up.

When I fill all fields and submit the form the alert `CCCCCCC` pops up (!!!). In addition the `ajaxResults` div gets the `.alert` and `.allert-success` classes, but still can't see any message.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

**Additional question**: Is the `error: function(response)` used to show the the case where validation fails ?

I have also tried to move the validation errors inside this function and keep on `success : function(response)` only the success submition of the form, but still no luck.

Comment: Need more info ..can you  Please copy  "Response.message "  - once you  have submitted form

Comment: Firstly  you  have got syntax wrong  in  form_open it should  be "form_open('home/form-process' ,array('id' => 'modal-form')); "

Comment: if you just want to show error message put `<?php form_error("first_name")?>` after every input field this shows error crossponding to first_name etc

Comment: How can I get the validation errors individually and display each one on the appropriate field ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem" was this `output->set_status_header($response['status'])` the request was always successful, but setting a header to 400 messed up the functionality.

I removed this piece of code and now works fine! However I still needed to add the

```
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {   
    alert(thrownError) ; // or alert(xhr.responseText); 
     $('#ajaxResults').addClass('alert alert-error').html(thrownError) ;       
}
```

to get any errors in cases that the request fail.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are not parsing the data properly

example : in `alert('DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD');` line

before appending data to your   ajaxResults  you  need to convert data Properly

- response.responseText  => will give  you  json string .

  [JSON.parse](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) => will convert string to JSON Obj so that you can
  use it like .variableName

Please add the following code before your
 `$('#ajaxResults').addClass('alert alert-error').html(response.reason);`

add following line

```
var mess = JSON.parse(response.responseText).message;
```

replace `response.reason` to `mess`   it should show you error Messages

Please mark it as answer if it works

full Code :

```
 if (response.status == 400) { 
                                $('#modal-form').show();
                                 var mess = JSON.parse(response.responseText).message;
                                $('#ajaxResults').addClass('alert alert-error').html(mess);
                                alert('DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD');
                            }
```

working [image]

Answer (score 0):

If it takes you to the error part, then you must use something like this to catch it:

```
,
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {   
    alert(thrownError) ; // or alert(xhr.responseText); 
     $('#ajaxResults').addClass('alert alert-error').html(thrownError) ;       
}
```

And if the ajax call is successful, something like this:

```
,
succes: function(data, status, jqXHR){
   if (status == 200) {
      $('#modal-form').hide();
      $('#ajaxResults').addClass('alert alert-success').html(response.message);
      alert(data);
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem seemed to be in this line in my controller `$this->output->set_status_header($response['status'])` .. I comment out this piece of code and worked. Both cases (success and failure) work inside `success : function(response)` correct.

Comment: Is this `error: function` or `success:function` the same thing like doing `.error(function)` or `.success(function)` right outside the `$.ajax()` ??